# Landscape orientation file not running

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a landscape file by clicking create landscape variation. When I run the emulator, the landscape file did not run at all, however, it's recognized in the design tab between portrait and landscape option.

This is my first time following a tutorial to create a landscape version of my app, should I write some code in the android manifest or my main to detect the orientation change?

Edit: I'm expecting the app to run the portrait file when it's portrait and landscape file when it's landscape

[image: My project files]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make sure your emulator has autorotate turned on.  If its off, the device won't show any landscape layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You can turn on auto rotate feature from your phone or emulator.

2.if you want to use landscape mode only then specify that on
your manifest file like this

```
  <activity
        android:name=".ui.VideoList"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.yb.MainActivity"
        />
```

Comment: I'm expecting the app to run the portrait file when it's portrait and landscape file when it's landscape. Can you advise on that?

Comment: then you don't need to do anything.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my problem, I didn't think I have to do anything else but my app is not running the landscape file

Comment: try it on real device or use bluestack